# pthread slower than no thread at all

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

hello i tried to add thread to my towerdefence to make it faster but it is way slower now.

the structure of the code is quite simple

the main starting with sdl opengl init and init everything. then game loop.
no thread order:
1:keyboard and mouse event first
2:gameManager
3:drawGlScene

gameManager calculate everything: move monster, attack monster, create attack animation and sound,check if you win or loose, if wave is done, monster spawning and the function run 2 time if speed mode is on. and some other small feature.

drawing function use all data to draw everything. there is 0 data modification withing the drawing function

the cpu i use is quad core and here are the visual part
first step init thread stuff in main

```
int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
 pthread_t t_engine;
 pthread_attr_t attr;
 pthread_attr_init(&attr);
 pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
```

then all other init stuff and start of game loop
start with sdl event switch then (still in game loop):

```
//calculate everything if we are in playing gamestate
    if(id == MODE_PLAY)
    {
        rc = pthread_create(&t_engine, &attr, gameManager, (void *)t);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        //gameManager((void *)t);
    }

    //draw everything
    DrawGLScene();

if(id == MODE_PLAY)
    {
        rc = pthread_join(t_engine, &status);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

gameManager:

```
void *gameManager(void *t)
{
  //then lot of stuff
  //function ending like this
  pthread_exit((void*) t);
}
```

ps:i am using windows 7 and my ide is codeblock and i use gnu gcc compiler
pps:i also tried mutex, sem and other stuff but nothing did a real difference
thanks you for taking the time to help me (=

Comment: Threads are not a magic bullet you just throw at your code to make it faster, you have to plan and understand what you're doing. I would suggest taking a step back and reading a bit first.

Comment: How long does your program run? Do the main thread and the spawned thread share much data? How are they synchronized? The question is impossible to answer with anything other than: *as with many other features, your mileage will vary*

Comment: most tutorial i found about pthread are very basic and dont talk about a lot of stuff. but i can tell you that the drawing function read lots of data manipulated by gameManager. i never got any bug from it. the drawing function write absolutely nothing.

Comment: You need to understand what is slow, and why, before you can make it faster!

Comment: From the posted code it looks like you are spawning a thread once per iteration of your game's event loop, then waiting for the thread to exit.  If that's the case, then there's little wonder that things are slower than before... spawning a thread 30-60 times a second, (and waiting for it to exit each time) would definitely slow things down.

Answer (score 5):

This bit from your explanation of the problem:

> then all other init stuff and start of game loop

makes me believe that the snippet of code that does the `pthread_create()`/`pthread_join()` above is done in a loop.

If that's the case, realize that repeatedly creating/destroying threads is expensive.  You'll want to look into putting a game loop in your `gameManger` object and synchronizing that loop with the loop that executes the `DrawGLScene()` using something like semaphores, condition variables or thread barriers.  Almost anything other than using thread termination as your synchronization technique.